# Finding Correlations between text and specific words extracted from text

Tags: r, correlation, text-mining

I am trying to do correlation analysis between text and few keywords ( extracted based on frequency >200 ) extracted from the same text .

I am unsure how can i do it using R .

Here is a snippet of data .The main data is coded( by default )  as levels in R

```
head(data)
[1] Call of star wars a halos destiny                                                       
[2] I thought of an new call of duty name CALL OF DUTY: The road of ARK GIANT               
[3] Activation must be destroyed for the sake of video games. Boycott those pieces of shits.
[4] Futuristic˜                                                                          
[5] 1:09 is that the XM 53
```

Few Keywords analysed from the cleaned text corpus

```
head(label)
[1] "2016"    "action"  "activis" "actual"  "alreadi" "also"
```

I am trying to achieve a correlation matrix which looks at how correlated a word is in the text and finally will use that correlation matrix to form a network graph to detect communities

But my aim at this point is to create a table or a matrix like one below

```
                                                star  destroyed  duty 
Call of star wars a halo destiny                  1       0       0
Activation must be destroyed for the sake ....    0       1       0
I thought of new call of duty star                1       0       1
```

Similarly for all the data text [ total of 13281 lines] , label [ a total of 202 words)

Comment: Please provide more detail regarding what it is you are actually trying to achieve, and what it is you've already tried.

Comment: Dear Figurine , I have edited the post and pasted a screenshot of how i want my output to look in R , please do have a look

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are just concerned about the presence (1) or absence (0) of a label in the data text, the following should work for you:

```
data <- c('Call of star wars a halo destiny',
         'I thought of an new call of duty star',
         'Activation must be destroyed for the sake .... ',
         'Futuristic˜',
         '1:09 is that the XM 53')
label <- c("2016","action","activis","actual", "alreadi","also", "star", "destroyed", "duty")

vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern', SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
df <- +(vgrepl(tolower(label), tolower(data))) # case insensitive
rownames(df) <- data

df

                                                 2016 action activis actual alreadi also star destroyed duty
Call of star wars a halo destiny                   0      0       0      0       0    0    1         0    0
I thought of an new call of duty star              0      0       0      0       0    0    1         0    1
Activation must be destroyed for the sake ....     0      0       0      0       0    0    0         1    0
Futuristic˜                                        0      0       0      0       0    0    0         0    0
1:09 is that the XM 53                             0      0       0      0       0    0    0         0    0
```